# Maximum recursion, GCD(greatest common divisor)

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a program to find gcd using python.

```
def gcd(a,b):
    r=a%b
    if r==0:
        return a
    elif r==1:
        return 1
    else:
        gcd(a,b)==gcd(b,r)
        return gcd(b,r)
```

Whenever I call the function it shows the message "Max. recursion exceeded." Please help
I know it can be done using looping but I want to specifically do it by using recursion method. And bear with me. I am a learner!

Comment: Why are you doing a check for equality?

Comment: what is `gcd(a,b)==gcd(b,r)` supposed to do?

Comment: Beside the recursion fix, I think you have en error on the formula, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is unnecessary and it's the one making the recursion endless: `gcd(a,b)==gcd(b,r)` because it's calling `gcd(a,b)` again and again. Just remove it:

```
def gcd(a,b):
    r=a%b
    if r==0:
        return a
    elif r==1:
        return 1
    return gcd(b,r)
```

Note: By the way, you got the formula wrong, you should return `b` on the if clause since you're dividing `a/b` when calculating the modulo.

```
def gcd(a,b):
    r=a%b
    if r==0:
        return b
    elif r==1:
        return 1
    return gcd(b,r)

>>>gcd(10,4)
2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to calculate the GCD of very large numbers (e.g., when searching for [common factors in RSA moduli](https://www.google.com/?q=rsa+common+prime+attack)), you might be better off avoiding recursion altogether and using an iterative function instead. For example:

```
def gcd(a,b):
    while a:
        a,b = b%a,a
    return b
```

Comment: see [Turbo method for calculating GCD.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3918647/432081)

Answer (score 1):

`gcd(a,b)==gcd(b,r)` doesn't do what you expect it to do.

It doesn't mean "define gcd(a,b) to be equal to gcd(b,r)".

Instead, `gcd(a,b)==gcd(b,r)` means:

- Compute `gcd(a,b)`
- Compute `gcd(b,r)`
- Compare the two results and see if they're equal.

Since you're asking to compute `gcd(a, b)` in order to compute `gcd(a, b)`, you'll get an endless recursion.

Instead, you want the `return gcd(b, r)` at that point. I.e.:

```
def gcd(a,b):
    r=a%b
    if r==0:
        return a
    elif r==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return gcd(b,r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
    def gcd(m,n):
      if m >= n:
      r = m % n
        if r == 0:
         return n
        else:
          m = n
          n = r
          return gcd(m,n)
      else:
        temp = m
        m = n
        n = temp
        return gcd(m,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if a % b == 0:
       return b
    return gcd(b, a % b)
```